# The same query on MySQL takes either less than a second or tens of minutes (InnoDB engine)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I execute the same query several times with exactly same parameters unders the same user name when there is no other operations in the database; server is idle mostly. MySQL version is 8.15.0 on Windows server (Azure box) with InnoDB engine.

Most of the time the query execution takes forever - that means the corresponding thread remains in status "Sending data" for more than 30 minutes and then I kill it.

***But sometimes it produces results in 0,002 sec (how it should to my understanding)***

The leading table stores around 100 000 records, one of the involved tables has almost a million.

The original select is:

```
SELECT part_1.* 
FROM `peps.VSessionRunFileList` as part_1 
WHERE 1 = 1 and 
part_1.`SessionUUID` = 0xD565EC62BDFC11EAB5571736CB554B78 AND 
part_1.`RunId` = 138 
ORDER BY 1 
LIMIT 151 OFFSET 0
```

The select operates with a view which has MERGE algorithm, the underlying select is as follows:

```
SELECT
    jrf.`FileName` as `Name`,
    jrf.`SessionUUID`,
    jrf.`RunId`,
    file.`StoragePath`,
    coalesce(fip.`lines`, 0) as `Lines`,
    file.`Size`,
    file.`ImportedSize`,
    file.`Format`,
    file.`CreatedOn`,
    fup.`StartedOn` as `UploadStartedOn`,
    fup.`EndedOn` as `UploadedOn`,
    fip.`StartedOn` as `ImportStartedOn`,
    fip.`EndedOn` as `CompletedOn`,
    file.`FileCreatedOn`,
    CAST(fup.`Ended` as UNSIGNED) AS `Uploaded`,
    CAST(fip.`Ended` as UNSIGNED) AS `Complete`,
    CAST(file.`Aborted` as UNSIGNED) AS `Aborted`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, fup.`StartedOn`, fup.`EndedOn`) as `UploadDuration`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, fip.`StartedOn`, fip.`EndedOn`) as `ImportDuration`,
    file.`DigestAlgorithm`,
    file.`OriginalDigest`,
    file.`Digest`,
    (select count(*) from `peps.ImportSessionLog` 
        where `SessionUUID` = jrf.`SessionUUID`
        AND `FileName` = jrf.`FileName`
        AND `RunId` = jrf.`RunId`
        AND `Level` = 0) as `ErrorCount`,
    (select count(*) from `peps.ImportSessionLog` 
        where `SessionUUID` = jrf.`SessionUUID`
        AND `FileName` = jrf.`FileName`
        AND `RunId` = jrf.`RunId`
        AND `Level` = 1) as `WarningCount`,
    coalesce(fup.`percentage`, 0) AS `UploadPercentage`,
    coalesce(fip.`percentage`, 0) AS `ImportPercentage`,
    CASE
        WHEN file.`Digest` = file.`OriginalDigest` THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS `ValidCheckSum`,
    job.`SystemUUID`,
    file.`DataCategory`,
    job.`DataCategory` as `JobDataCategory`,
    job.`SubCategory`,
    job.`SessionType`
FROM
    `peps.JobRunFiles` as jrf
    INNER JOIN `peps.ImportSession` AS job ON job.`UUID` = jrf.`SessionUUID`
    INNER JOIN `peps.Files` AS file ON file.`Name` = jrf.`FileName`
    AND file.`SessionUUID` = jrf.`SessionUUID`
    LEFT JOIN `peps.FileProgress` AS fip ON fip.`SessionUUID` = jrf.`SessionUUID`
    AND fip.`FileName` = jrf.`FileName`
    AND fip.`RunId` = jrf.`RunId`
    AND fip.`Operation` = 'IMPORT'
    LEFT JOIN `peps.FileProgress` AS fup ON fup.`SessionUUID` = jrf.`SessionUUID`
    AND fup.`FileName` = jrf.`FileName`
    AND fup.`RunId` = jrf.`RunId`
    AND fup.`Operation` = 'UPLOAD'
```

When I execute EXPLAIN it shows that it plans to use PRIMARY or foreign keys indices. The where condition contains all the primary keys of the leading table and all join conditions are with EQ operations.

```
# id    select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY job     const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 18  const   1   100.00  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY file        ALL PRIMARY             104300  10.00   Using where
1   PRIMARY jrf     eq_ref  PRIMARY,JobRunFilesDel  PRIMARY 405 const,const,elsa_dev.file.Name  1   100.00  Using where; Using index
1   PRIMARY fip     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 467 elsa_dev.file.Name,const,const,const    1   100.00  Using where
1   PRIMARY fup     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 467 elsa_dev.file.Name,const,const,const    1   100.00  Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  peps.importsessionlog       ref ImportSessionLogDel ImportSessionLogDel 18  elsa_dev.jrf.SessionUUID    42733   0.10    Using index condition; Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  peps.importsessionlog       ref ImportSessionLogDel ImportSessionLogDel 18  elsa_dev.jrf.SessionUUID    42733   0.10    Using index condition; Using where
```

Tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE `peps.jobrunfiles` (
  `SessionUUID` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `RunId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FileName` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SessionUUID`,`RunId`,`FileName`),
  KEY `JobRunFilesDel` (`FileName`,`SessionUUID`),
  CONSTRAINT `JobRunFilesDel` FOREIGN KEY (`FileName`, `SessionUUID`) REFERENCES `peps.files` (`Name`, `SessionUUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) /*!50100 TABLESPACE `innodb_system` */ ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `peps.importsession` (
  `UUID` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `SystemUUID` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CurrentRunId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `Started` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `StartedBy` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompletedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompletedBy` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Aborted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `AbortedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AbortedBy` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `FromDesktop` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `FilePath` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `DataCategory` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubCategory` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SessionType` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CurrentRunListId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartParams` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `peps.files` (
  `Name` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `SessionUUID` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Format` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `FileCreatedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Size` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ImportedSize` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Complete` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `DataCategory` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lines` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `CreatedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImportStartedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompletedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompletedBy` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Aborted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `AbortedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AbortedBy` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `DigestAlgorithm` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `OriginalDigest` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Digest` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Uploaded` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `UploadStartedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `UploadedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `UploadedBy` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `HeaderFileName` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `StoragePath` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Inconsistencies` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTUALSIZE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Name`,`SessionUUID`)
) /*!50100 TABLESPACE `innodb_system` */ ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `peps.fileprogress` (
  `FileName` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `SessionUUID` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `RunId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Operation` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `StartedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ended` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `percentage` double DEFAULT '0',
  `transferred` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `length` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `remaining` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `eta` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `runtime` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `delta` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `speed` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `lines` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`FileName`,`SessionUUID`,`RunId`,`Operation`),
  CONSTRAINT `FileProgressDel` FOREIGN KEY (`FileName`, `SessionUUID`) REFERENCES `peps.files` (`Name`, `SessionUUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) /*!50100 TABLESPACE `innodb_system` */ ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

What can be wrong with the query?

Comment: That EXPLAIN is totally not for that query. All the table references have the wrong names, and there are no subqueries in the query you show. It doesn't even have the same number of tables.

Comment: Thank you very much, posted wrong query (struggling with 2 requests with the same behaviour)

Comment: Something is not quite right. The `ref` in the EXPLAIN shows a lot of cases of `const` but the query has joins to table columns, not constant values. I would expect `const` to be shown for example when you compare to `fip.`Operation` = 'IMPORT'` because 'IMPORT' is a constant value. But not in cases where the join is based on a column reference.

Comment: Also I usually make this request: when you ask for help with query optimization, you need to include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` for each table, so we know what primary keys, indexes, constraints, data types, collations, etc. you have defined in each table. Don't make us guess at those things! Help us to help you!

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, edited the question

Comment: Downvoting because neither `VSessionRunFileList` nor `file` are defined.

Comment: @RickJames - both VSessionRunFileList and file are defined. Please reread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the updates. Adding the table definitions and the main query that calls the view is what was needed. Now we see where the `const` references come from, they are terms in the WHERE clause of the main query.

I notice in the EXPLAIN, it orders the `file` table before the `jrf` table, which is strange because it would need the filename from `jrf` to select the matching rows in `file`. Since it's joining to `file` before it gets the relevant filename, it is forced to do a table-scan (`type:ALL`) and examine 104,300 rows in the `file` table. That's probably the source of the poor performance.

The cases where you see very fast performance are probably exception cases, where the optimizer does the joins in a proper order, joining to `file` after it joins to `jrf`.

You could try to force a table join order by using [STRAIGHT_JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

```
...
FROM
`peps.JobRunFiles` as jrf
STRAIGHT_JOIN `peps.ImportSession` AS job 
  ON job.`UUID` = jrf.`SessionUUID`
STRAIGHT_JOIN `peps.Files` AS file 
  ON file.`Name` = jrf.`FileName`
  AND file.`SessionUUID` = jrf.`SessionUUID`
```

I would hope this turns the `type:ALL` join method for the `file` table into `type:eq_ref` (i.e. primary key lookup), and that will turn the `rows:104300` into `rows:1`.

I don't know why it was doing the join in the wrong order most of the time. Maybe some odd VIEW behavior.

Comment: Many thanks Bill STRAIGHT_JOIN helped - at least it returns back in 10 sec. After some experimenting I see that for now moving count calculation into a separate view improved the performance, so now it's back in 1 sec. Not sure though if it does not degrade in a while, will see.